# any way to suppress semicolon between citations in footnotes?

Tags: pandoc

Hoping this is the right place for this question--

I'm writing a document in Markdown with a bibliography exported from Zotero using Better BibTeX, and I'm citing a source via a footnote that in turn quotes another source, and the proper (law review article) format in the footnote is

`<source1> (quoting <source2>).`

In my Markdown text I have

`[@Reed, p. 25; \(quoting @vol3, p. 408)]`

This comes very close to rendering the neededed format in the footnote BUT includes an unwanted semicolon after the second source--so the format it's producing is:

`<source1>; (quoting <source2>).`

Is there a way to suppress that semicolon between citations in particular instances? Wouldn't want have it suppressed universally/still need the semicolon between cites in most instances, but need to suppress it any time one source cites or quotes another source (which requires a parenthetical indication starting with "quoting" or "citing").

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this these technologies, so this is a guess, but can't you simply delete the semicolon from the markdown?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’d like to add a prefix for citations, which is supported for Pandoc’s [citation syntax](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations). For your use-case, just use `[@Reed, p. 25; quoting @vol3, p. 408]`.